# Copy Files phase is getting last build's product

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an app that has an embedded helper app. I have an Xcode behavior configured so that the bundle version of both apps is incremented each time the app is built. The problem is, I'm finding that unless I clean my build folder every time, version `N` of my app gets version `N - 1` of the helper. This isn't just a version number mismatch—the helper app's binary does not contain the changes I've just made.

My basic setup is like so:

[image: "Typesetter Toolkit Helper" is included in a Target Dependencies phase at the top, and "Typesetter Toolkit Helper.app" is listed in a Copy Files phase at the bottom, being copied to "Contents/Helpers" in destination "Wrapper".]

To attempt to simulate cleaning the build folder in a more targeted way, I wrote a tiny Perl script that runs in a Run Script phase just before the Copy Files phase that adds the helper, but it had no effect:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path qw(remove_tree);

my $dir = "$ENV{TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/$ENV{WRAPPER_NAME}/Contents/Helpers";
if(-e $dir) {
    remove_tree $dir or die "Can't rmtree $dir: $!";
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on? How can I keep my helper and its host in sync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script runs before the copy phase so I think you want the BUILD_DIR not the TARGET_BUILD_DIR.

```
BUILD_DIR = /Users/gdunham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DC_Wire_Sizer-csvpfesmgmorlhendyncafecwzam/Build/Products
TARGET_BUILD_DIR = /Users/gdunham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DC_Wire_Sizer-csvpfesmgmorlhendyncafecwzam/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
```

**Tip**: I generally check "Show environment variable in build log" for my run script build phases. You can also print from your script and view the output by expanding the build phase transcript. Select your run script in the  the log navigator and in Xcode's menu select "**Editor**" -> "**Expand Selected Transcript**".

Comment: That seems to have done the trick—I didn't realize it was being built elsewhere and then moved to the final location. Thanks!